# Magento2: How to get order total price

Tags: magento2, cart, order-totals

I am developing a Magento 2 Payment Gateway
now I need to get order total to make the payment
how to get it on Magento 2 using Magento Cart Models?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$grandTotal = $cart->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the subtotal using following code :

// Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier;

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{

    $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
```